# Use statement for @OneToOne - Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table with Products and another table with Notes. Each product can have or not some notes. I need only the notes to know to which product they are reffered, but the product not to know about its notes. I think that this should be my code:

```
namespace EM\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use EM\MyBundle\Entity\Productss;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="notes")
 */
class Notess
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Productss")
 * @JoinColumn(name="products_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $products; 
//... 
}

namespace EM\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="domains")
 */
class Domains
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
// ...
}
```

but it gives an error:    [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToOne" in property EM\MyBundle\
Entity\Notes::$products was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use
" statement for this annotation?

Can you please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think you were meant to use `@ORM\OneToOne` instead...

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Productss")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="products_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $products; 
//... 
}
```

Comment: This problems arises whatever type of relationship it is: oneToMany, oneToOne or manyToMany, because of the documentation. I've had the same problem only making copy/paste of the official documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: This would be because the doctrine documentation assume you would be `use`ing each `@`class so all annotations use the actual class name (`use Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/OneToOne` => `@OneToOne`), where as Symfony recommends the `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM` namespace approach so all of the annotations use the ORM as a base(`@ORM\OneToOne`).